# VBA OneDrive Sync Excel File pending

Tags: excel, vba, synchronization, office365, onedrive

I am using an excel file as a shared database stored in one drive.
Technically talking it's an excel file called DataBase.xlsx that I store in microsoft teams, and I used the SYNC function of microsoft teams to create a shortcut in my windows explorer here is how it looks like.

[image]

I have another excel file MyTool.xlsm with macros to insert Data into the DataBase.xlsx file.
The problem is that when I add new data using the MyTool.xlsm, the data are inserted into the DataBase.xlsx, but the sync keeps pending and never stop by it's own. Thus, each time I add Data to the shared DataBase, other users can't see what I added because it's pending and not sync to the server.
Here is how it looks like when I insert Data.

[image]

I noticed that If after I finish adding the data through MyTool.xlsm, and that the SYNC icon appears like pending forever, if I open manually the file and save it, the sync pending will stop directly and the Sync succeed.

[image]

Any idea how to solve that problem and avoid getting the SYNC pending when adding Data to DataBase.xlsx using MyTool.xlsm ?
Thanks in advance.

Here is the code that I am using in MyTool.xlsm to insert the DataBase.xlsx

```
Public Sub InsertToSharedDataBase()
    
    Dim sFullFileName As String
    Dim SharedDataBaseWb As Workbook
    Dim SharedDataBaseWs As Worksheet
      
    sFullFileName = "C:\Users\tk\MyCompanyOneDrine\MyFolder\Database.xlsx"

    'I am using GetOject to open my wb with a hidden way (I know I can use differnt ways to open it)
    'Like this way for example : Set SharedDataBaseWb = Workbooks.Open(sFullFileName)
    'In both cases I am getting the same problem.
      
    Set SharedDataBaseWb = GetObject(sFullFileName)
    Set SharedDataBaseWs = SharedDataBaseWb.Worksheets("MyWorksheet")
    
    'I add some data to the worksheet using a code like that

    With SharedDataBaseWs
    .Cells(1, 1).Value2 = "values"
    .Cells(1, 2).Value2 = "values"
    .Cells(1, 3).Value2 = "values"
    .Cells(1, 4).Value2 = "values"
    End With
    
    'Saving the workbook
    SharedDataBaseWb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
    'Cleaning the used objects
    Set SharedDataBaseWs = Nothing
    Set SharedDataBaseWb = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Try calling the [Workbook.Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.save) method before closing the workbook. Does it help?

Comment: I just tried : SharedDataBaseWb.Save
SharedDataBaseWb.Close SaveChanges:=True, but nothing changed :(

Comment: Sounds like your code still holds a reference to any COM object used in the code. Try to clear/release all references by setting them to `Nothing` in VBA

Comment: I couldn't find any COM object that I didn't set to nothing, but when you asked me to separate the .Close from the .Save, it gaves me a hint that I am trying right now, will tell you the results, but is it logicial that if I add a .wait 5-10 seconds between after the .save that things go better ? Weird but it seems better if I stop the code 5-10 seconds after the .save ?

Comment: Does the delay help to avoid the issue?

Comment: yes, without the delay, I always have the databse with the sync Icon, If i add the delay, the database become green after my save...But the cloud continue the sync for abou 1 min ... without the delay, both the file and the cloud icon go into sync forever. Trying to make more tests to confirm what I am saying

Comment: Great! But I'd suggest breaking property and method calls into separate lines and releasing all underlying COM objects.

Comment: I don't think that I still having any COM object without release but I will check..On the same time, I need to find a way to check the SYNC status of one drive (any idea about), to make user wait till the cloud stops sync before saving anything new otherwise it will fail

Comment: The Excel object model doesn't provide anything for that.